# Is doing full body workouts and other sports too much?

Tags: workout-routines, workout, muscle-gain, sports

I have 3 days a week to go the gym, while during the weekends I rest, on Mondays, Wednesdays and Fridays I workout and on Tuesdays and Thursdays I play volleyball.

My workout routine is a full body workout 3x a week, So I was worried about my legs, since I train them 3x a week and jump a lot in volleyball. Is it too much And I should change my workout routine? Or is there a way I can conciliate these two things?

My workouts and meal plan are focused on muscle building.

Comment: It will be much easier to provide the answer you're looking for by giving us more details.  What are all the exercises you are performing on days you do full body workouts?  What are the set and reps you execute?  Also, what is your height, body weight, body fat percentage, and hours that you workout a week?  Diet is extremely important for recovery and if you're under eating, then you'll reach a point of overtraining and exhaustion.  This means that weight training and volleyball are going to suffer.

Comment: It depends on your goals. If your goal is to become a professional volleyball player, then maybe try breaking up your routine more and see if you feel fresher when you play. If you only play as a hobby and your gym work is more important, and volleyball doesn't effect your training, then you're all good. Given adequate rest and recovery, your body will adapt to the amount of work you're demanding of it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assess By yourself if you are overtrained or not. This depends on a lot of parameters e.g. your capacities, your sleep, your diet as well as external stress factors.

Training and competing equals imposing stress on the body. You want the stress  (training + external) to be compensated  (capacities + diet + recovery) to achieve adaptation and perform better in the end.

So an easy way to assess if you are over training is to check your performance. Do they keep increasing or do they decrease? A decrease indicates overtraining. Take care that à decrease in performance during à training cycle is possible and sometimes expected. You need ton assess your performances after a proper deload  (rest) week in such case.

Also difficulty to sleep and Other symptoms indicate overtraining. Google it to find all symptoms and assess yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Break up your muscle groups up and do legs on Friday so you'll have a couple days to recover before you hit the court on Tuesday. Playing volleyball with sore quads sounds like torture.